# using variables inside handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars helper that compares two values.   My code is below

```
{{#compare action "blank" operator="!="}}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-approval" data-id="{{../sid}}" data-table="distributor">Approve</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete-approval" data-id="{{../sid}}" data-table="distributor">Delete</button>
{{/compare}}
```

for some reason I can't access the sid variable inside the helper.  How would I do that?

Comment: can you get to sid in the parent context?

Comment: Can't help you without code. Here obsiously you didn't pass the page context to the contained sub template.

Comment: the comparison code or the full handlebars template

Comment: @WillEnglishIV The 'compare' helper or an external snippet thereof should suffice, in addition to some sample context that you're executing the template with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `sid` it as parameter to helper. And you can access it as an argument in helper function.

```
{{#compare ../sid  action "blank" operator="!="}}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-approval" data-id="{{sid}}" data-table="distributor">Approve</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete-approval" data-id="{{sid}}" data-table="distributor">Delete</button>
{{/compare}}
```

The helper function can then access it as an argument.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(sid, action, blank, operator, options) {
    this.sid = sid;
    // your code here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but what I ended up doing was making the logic inside my handler instead of doing it with handlebars